# HTML dynamic table with a column of <select> options - how to extract <select> values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table, that I create with this function:

```
function addRow(v1,v2)
{
       if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
       tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
       row=document.createElement("tr");
       cell1 = document.createElement("td");
       cell2 = document.createElement("td");
       cell3 = document.createElement("td");
       textnode1=document.createTextNode(v1);
       textnode2=document.createTextNode(v2);
       select = document.createElement('select');
       option1 = document.createElement("option");
       option1.setAttribute('value', "op1");
       option1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("op1"));
       select.appendChild(option1);
       option2 = document.createElement("option");
       option2.setAttribute('value', "op2");
       option2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("op2"));
       select.appendChild(option2);
       option3 = document.createElement("option");
       option3.setAttribute('value', "combine");
       option3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Combine"));
       select.appendChild(option3);
       cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
       cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
       cell3.appendChild(select)
       row.appendChild(cell1);
       row.appendChild(cell2);
       row.appendChild(cell3);
       tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

I'm extracting the table values:

```
var values = $('#difftable td') 
     .map(function(i, e){    
     return e.innerText; 
     })
     .get();
```

I'm getting values from first 2 columns, but not the select tag values from the third column. How can I find these values from the select tags ?

Comment: Your snippet does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing with it, here is the code that seems to work:

First, add id to each td element and select:

```
function addRow(v1,v2, idx)
{
       if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
       tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
       row=document.createElement("tr");
       cell1 = document.createElement("td");
       cell1.setAttribute('id', "tdv1" + idx);
       cell2 = document.createElement("td");
       cell2.setAttribute('id', "tdv2" + idx);
       cell3 = document.createElement("td");
       textnode1=document.createTextNode(v1);
       textnode2=document.createTextNode(v2);
       select = document.createElement('select');
       select.setAttribute('id', "selid" + idx);
       option1 = document.createElement("option");
       option1.setAttribute('value', "v1");
       option1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("v1"));
       select.appendChild(option1);
       option2 = document.createElement("option");
       option2.setAttribute('value', "v2");
       option2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("v2"));
       select.appendChild(option2);
       option3 = document.createElement("option");
       option3.setAttribute('value', "combine");
       option3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Combine"));
       select.appendChild(option3);
       cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
       cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
       cell3.appendChild(select)
       row.appendChild(cell1);
       row.appendChild(cell2);
       row.appendChild(cell3);
       tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

Then, in the script:

```
var len = $('#difftable').length;
values = new Array(len);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     values[i] = new Array(3);
     values[i][0] = document.getElementById("tdv1"+i).innerHTML;
     values[i][1] = document.getElementById("tdv2"+i).innerHTML;
                values[i][2] = document.getElementById("selid"+i).value;
}

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'MergeServlet',
data: {values:values},
success: function(data){
...
}
```

Still, would like to see a more elegant solution.